# SSL Handshake, Cannot Pinpoint Problem

Tags: authentication, ssl, certificate, certificate-authority

When attemting to communicate with an Alfresco Server to perform a file upload  the client receives the following error in their logs.

> [SSLPeerUnverifiedException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLPeerUnverifiedException.html):
>
> Indicates that the peer's identity has not been verified.
>
> When the peer was not able to identify itself (for example; no
>   certificate, the particular cipher suite being used does not support
>   authentication, or no peer authentication was established during SSL
>   handshaking) this exception is thrown.

I was attempting to break down the SSL handshake to see what is causing this error using steps around the [web](http://www.pierobon.org/ssl/ch2/detail.htm).

On which step does it look like the handshake is failing. I am leaning towards 3 but have no idea due to the following:

1. The error is only thrown during file uploads. (Downloads, browsing, etc all work fine.)
2. Certificates have been checked and are still valid
3. Certificates have been reupdated on the client
4. The certs were not in cacerts on the client before so they have not been put there

Is this error occuring serverside and something is misconfigured on the server? If so what could it be?

Comment: It seems that uploading has a different ssl configuration than download/browsing. Do you have apache/another webserver in front of alfresco? Another problem could be that the browser has actually two client certificates of that host and automatically selects the wrong one. Configure the browser for manual selection.

Comment: @AndreasM Thanks, there were two certificates but the client was only set to accept one. The other was added and everything is golden. If you elaborate your comment into an answer I can give you some rep.

Comment: cool, see below. It's not entirely clear to me whether we're dealing with client or server certs. The error suggests that the server wants a client cert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that uploading has a different ssl configuration than download/browsing. A problem could be that the browser has actually two client certificates for that host/domain and automatically selects the wrong one.